# Google test : EXPECT_CALL fails to compile in my test code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest

I'm trying my 1st google test with gmock, setting all the VS environment ready. Simple usage of gtest ASSERT_XX functions works. But when trying to use gmock, I met first compiling issue. I guess maybe my program has some problem, but gtest doesn't tell me how to fix it.

In the program below, I got a class called "FileIo". Its "Read" function will do I/O, and I wish to mock this Read() function while keeping f() and g() unchanged. So I used NickMock to establish a mock object of FileIo, and then try to use EXPECT_CALL to fake a Read() function.

```
class FileIo
{
public:
    int f(){ return 1; }
    int g(int i){ return i*i; }
    int Read(){
        FILE* pf = fopen("D:\\a.txt", "r+w");
        fclose(pf);
        return 3;
    }
};

class BBTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:

};
TEST_F(BBTest, testcase_1)
{
    NiceMock<FileIo> mio;
    EXPECT_CALL(mio, Read()).WillRepeatedly(DoAll(Return(2)));
}
```

The statement of EXPECT_CALL failes compiling. How to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual compiler error that you're receiving.

Comment: You need to define a Mock class for FileIo.  You can't just wrap it in a `NiceMock` as you've done above.  See https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies#Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example for what you posted. I won't explain as it is in its simplest form. There are lots of examples out there that you can learn from. Google is your best friend. Search, read and learn.

```
class IFileIo
{
public:
    virtual int Read() = 0;
};

class FileIo : IFileIo
{
public:
    int Read() {
        FILE* pf = fopen("D:\\a.txt", "r+w");
        fclose(pf);
        return 3;
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    void ReadFile()
    {
        _file->Read();
    }
    IFileIo* _file;
};

class NiceMock : public IFileIo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Read, int());
};


class BBTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    NiceMock _mio;
};

TEST_F(BBTest, testcase_1)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(_mio, Read()).WillOnce(Return(2));
    MyClass mc;
    mc._file = &_mio;
    mc.ReadFile();
}
```